How to look for posts containing two words?
I'm having a problem with the ZoomControl control of my Utilities.dll file, so I decided to look for some information about it.
Google gave me (amongst others) the following answer:

That's indeed a link to a previous question I asked about a similar subject. Now I wanted to know if there are other posts about this subject, so I entered following words in the search box: Utilities ZoomControl, and this is the result I got:

This is even less than what I got from Google.
I have verified, and I can confirm the mentioned question is not deleted.
Why don't I see at least my own post when using the Stack Overflow search feature? What other posts might I be missing?

@yivi: I'm sorry, but I disagree with the total idea: "There is a search engine, which is better than the search feature of our site, so we are not forced to improve anything to the search feature of our site, even not when it has clear flaws." => I'm not expecting StackOverflow search feature to handle fuzzy searches or other advanced stuff, I just want the thing to work correctly.

"I just want the thing to work correctly" - don't we all

@yivi I think this should stay open because it's actually (per the answer given) about mitigating one specific issue with the site search.

@KarlKnechtel: thanks for helping reopening my question. Now what's next? As mentioned in my comment to Erik, the word separators should not only be spaces and newlines, but also dots, commas, .... I can imagine this having a huge impact on the website. Is there a list of actions to be done? How can I do any follow-up or any other contribution?

Stack Overflow search doesn't do partial word matching, nor does it split words on punctuation, so utilities won't match utilities.dll.
If you just search utilities.dll instead of utilities, you get your expected hit.
Alternatively, you can use wildcards to allow for partial matches by searching on *utilities* zoomcontrol. This returns your expected hit and many more.
There are existing feature requests on improving search, it isn't great...

Sorry, but I don't agree: the mentioned post contains the word "Utilities", like assembly=Utilities", so it should be found.

Nope, that's again not utilities separated by whitespace/newlines on both sides. 'Utilities, Version=3.1.... is the weirdest non-hit imo, probably because of that single quote.

That is wrong! When looking for the word "Utilities" you must find the case "assembly=Utilities": no one will treat this as a partial word matching. Apparently StackOverflow uses too less delimiters for separating entire words, leading to this erroneous behaviour. So this is a bug and it should be fixed. (I mean, you cannot say to people that it's not allowed to write duplicate questions if the site's search engine is not even capable of finding duplicates)

Well, it's one of the many things wrong with search. I don't disagree that search should be fixed, and that splitting words on punctuation would be a good improvement. It's just not a "match multiple words" bug as your question title implies, which is why I answered. And search is so awful that a more systemic approach (e.g. their previous attempt to replace the search engine) probably is a better idea.

It may also be a problem (I have not tested) that 'Utilities, Version=3.1.... appears in code.  Search handles code results ... differently.  I have yet to quite work out all the quirks of how it works.
